# Is it possible to add an AppDelegate to an independent watchOS SwiftUI app?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, appdelegate, watchos, uiapplicationdelegate

I am trying to add an AppDelegate to a standalone watchOS SwiftUI app (no companion iOS app) as indicated in [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app), but I can't seem to resolve the issue ***Cannot find type 'UIApplicationDelegate' in scope***

Explicitly adding an import UIKit does not help.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate

`UIApplicationDelegate` seems to only work with Catalyst, iOS and TvOS. Per WatchKit documentation it using the `WKExtensionDelegate` that has all the same methods.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/working_with_the_watchos_app_life_cycle

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate